Can I avoid being targeted specifically by spells by having a support character hold an invisible curtain in front of my PC?
It appears there is a consensus that any physical obstacle—whether a delicate, transparent pane of glass or a gossamer curtain—can provide total cover from incoming spells, according to RAW.
Sources supporting this interpretation include:

Is 'cover' simply about being out of sight? What IS cover?
How does Wall of Force grant cover?
Can you counter a spell through wall of force?
Can spells be cast through a Wall of Force?
Can sacred flame target someone that is behind total cover?
Can a spell be cast through (semi) transparent things?

According to the cover rules, this prevents targeting--at least with spells. Therefore, per RAW, a PC cannot be targeted by any spells, including those that do not require attack rolls.
Now, some support characters, e.g. an Imp Familiar, can fly, turn invisible, and wear/carry objects, whereby

... Any equipment [it] wears or carries is invisible with it.

Therefore, it appears that a PC can gain total cover by having a support character, such as an Imp Familiar, lower an invisible curtain over it. This action protects the PC from spells, outright preventing anyone or anything from targeting the PC with spells.
Is this interpretation of the RAW correct?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Does wearing clothing count as full cover? It would with this kind of ruling.

I agree, @SeriousBri. It seems totally absurd that something like an invisible curtain could provide cover from spells. Likewise, though, it seems absurd that a pane of glass could.

Ah now I understand the premise of the question, and I agree. Glass doesn't provide cover in my games unless the spell is a beam that is physically trying to pass through.

I’ve rolled back your “edit for clarification”, as it is just asking for answers to some of the questions you linked, rather than to this one. If you feel the linked questions haven’t been adequately addressed, you can bounty them. But this question is not the place to ask for more answers to them. This questions asks a specific and distinct question, about a proposed source of otherwise mundane cover that is invisible. Editing in additional questions about wall of force and non-invisible cover isn’t appropriate for this question.

Related: Does hiding under a bedsheet provide Total Cover by RAW?

. . . well, you can certainly try.
You say:

Therefore, it appears that a PC can gain total cover by having a support character, such as an Imp Familiar, lower an invisible curtain over it. This action protects the PC from spells, outright preventing anyone or anything from targeting the PC with spells.


Is this interpretation of the RAW correct?

This is, my opinion, nonsense.
You're trying to build a logical structure of dubious propositions to get some sort of iron-clad result where you can say, "but RAW!".
Phah!
First of all, "grant total cover".  You're thinking video game, not D&D.  You're trying to find some rule trick.  Granted, you've found an edge case, maybe, but nothing that you can build a RAW ruling on.
Here's how this should go:
Player: Hey, DM, my imp is holding an invisible curtain in front of me, they're always imposing it between me and the lich, only moving it aside when I tell them to thereby granting me total cover, so I am invulnerable to the lich and it is vulnerable to me!  Suck on that!
DM: Okay, so your imp has an invisible curtain and it is attempting to hold it in front of you.  You said some stuff after that but that wasn't describing your action, so . . . as the kids say these days . . . whatever.  But this is interesting. By the way, it might be nice to discuss tricks like this out of session, but that's okay.  I'm intrigued, let's see what happens.
DM: Anyway, tell me about this curtain.
Player: It's like cheese cloth . . . .
DM: Okay, stop there.  Cheese cloth is like 80% not there, so, this time, I'll grant it a 20% chance of stopping a spell.  Roll a plain D20 for me, 17 or better blocks the spell.
Player:  But . . . total cover!
DM: Bah.  Total cover is about obstacles and not being able to see things.  You're waving a cheesecloth flag around.  An invisible cheesecloth flag.  Allowing that to make you perfectly invulnerable is just silly.  Roll.
Player:  Okay, fine. 17!
DM: Okay, amazingly, your trick worked!  The lightning bolt hit the curtain.  It is incinerated, but it stopped the lightning bolt!  I gotta tell you, I'm giving it to you this time, but I'm not sure that really works.  I'll have to think on it a bit.  I'm just not sure some gauze can stop a lightning bolt, even once.  If you really want to pursue this, I think it's going to be very dependent on what the curtain is and what the magic is.
Player: What do you mean it's incinerated?
DM: Read the spell . . . . it went up like flash paper.  It was really cool, because it was invisible, and then boom, it was on fire.
DM: Also . . . how wide is this curtain?
Player: Umm, 5 feet.
DM: Okay, so the imp is trying to hold it in front of you, the lightning bolt is 5 feet wide.  Roll a dex save for the imp, to see if it managed to get the curtain centered right on you.  You need a . . . 14.
Player:  Umm, 9.
DM: Hmm.  To the left or the right, I wonder?  Okay, roll a 2-sided die.  On a 1, the imp's out of the way, on a two, the imp got caught in the bolt and took the full blast.
Player:  Umm, 2?
DM: Too bad about the imp.  Hey, I like this.  Be aware, this sort of shenanigans will never be a get-out-of-jail free card.  I mean shenanigans in the best possible sense, in this case.  I like it.  This is fun.  Feel free to experiment with materials and whatnot.  We can talk about it out of session.  Think about some of the parameters.  The heavier, the harder for the imp to maneuver.  The lighter, the less protective.  Also, I should have included a check for the cheesecloth wafting around.  Next time.  I am more than happy to take the game to a new tactical level.  If you enjoy tricks like this the monsters got some I think you'll really get a charge out of.  I'm getting fired up thinking about it.  I mean, I'm really feeling impish about this.  What, too soon?
Finally
I gave you a pretty broad answer, because it's a pretty broad question.  I think it is interesting to ponder what sort of cover and/or barrier does fabric of a particular type create?  That's an interesting question.  I think invisibility obscures (heh heh) the issue, because what you're really after is what are reasonable rulings around insubstantial barriers.  There may be an interesting question there.
Also, make sure you look at it (literally) from both sides.  What if the DM uses this tactic?  How should it go?  If the bad guy has an imp holding an invisible curtain in front of it, what is fair to you the player?

In case there is any ambiguity, I believe cheesy shenanigans like this should not work. But, I can't imagine why they wouldn't, if this works for Wall of Force. You may substitute the cheese (I see what you did there) cloth, for something more substantial.

I think the shenanigans are fine.  You just don't get an automatic win out of it.  How much of a barrier cloth is is an open question, imo.  Cloth isn't glass, and it isn't a wall of force.  I think it is reasonable to want to play this way, at a particular table, but if you're going to play this way, then play this way.  The DM has to figure out how to figure out how much of a barrier some substance is.  Usually D&D doesn't get that granular.  Usually, for instance, we ignore lightning bolt and fireball setting everything on fire.  But cloth as a barrier, for sure it should catch on fire.

But the rules are very abstract, and don't cover all the many possibilities.  Don't even begin to.  Look at half cover.  That could reasonably be many different cases, all lumped into half cover for convenience and to keep the game fast.

Since the invisible cheese curtain is being "worn or carried." it actually would not ignite.

Right, it should be looked at from both sides. I'd be disappointed if I used a high level spell slot on something only to find out an invisible cheese curtain neutralized it.

"Since the invisible cheese curtain is being "worn or carried." it actually would not ignite."  That is a good point.  Not sure you should be able to have it both ways, though.  If the cheesecloth curtain doesn't ignite because the imp is holding it, I think that means the imp gets lightning bolted.  On the other hand, if the imp has it on a stick, maybe the curtain still goes up in flames, but the imp has a chance to avoid the bolt (or whatever).

Listen, I agree with the spirit of what you're saying and your suggestions for how a DM should adjudicate this very specific example. But, what if it's not lightning bolt? What if it's mind sliver, or any number of other edge cases? It seems reasonable to take a similar approach, by making rulings according to what seems fair in a given instance. But, if I can adjudicate a mind sliver past the invisible curtain, I should also be able to mind sliver past a wall of force, right?

You might want to consider posting some of these as separate questions.  However, I don't think you can bootstrap cheesecloth into wall of force.  Cheesecloth is flimsy, and is literally mostly holes.  That's just a completely different thing than a wall of force.

I agree that's how it should be, but I guess when it comes down to non-physical spells that don't involve attack rolls, they operate essentially by the same mechanics

It depends on if you consider a curtain an obstacle
The rules for cover (p. 196 PHB) say:

A target has total cover if it is completely concealed by an obstacle.

What an obstacle is, is not further defined. There are designer statements that a pane of glass would block a clear path to the target for spells, so for spells this could possibly work. The line of effect of a spell does not exert force in the same way a physical attack does, and thus has no way to pierce the curtain.
However, mundane objects, like an arrow or a thin curtain generally behave as we expect them to. It's not clear, if a curtain would present an obstacle for an arrow. You probably can shoot an arrow right through a thin curtain of fabric, with little loss of its effectiveness. However, there are no explicit rules statements about what counts or does not count as an obstacle, so that is for the DM to decide.
Whether the curtain is invisible or not does not really affect if it counts as cover or not. The above quote is mentions complete concealment (which an invisible curtain wouldn't provide) but that is just because an intransparent obstacle that fully conceals you leaves no path to the target. It is not the concealment that causes the cover, it is that the thing that conceals you is in the way. The cover rules open with:

Walls, trees, creatures, and other obstacles can provide cover during combat, making a target more difficult
to harm.

What matters is if the curtain it presents an obstacle, or not, not if it offers concealment or not. A wall of force or a thick crystal wall would still provide cover without concealment, because they are obstacles.1
If I were your DM, I'd allow a curtain to provide heavy concealment if it were large enough and opaque, but no cover, because I would not consider it a meaningful obstacle for physical force such as an axe or an arrow. An invisible curtain likewise could not block such attacks, but it would block spells as you could not target them through it and it could fool an opposing spellcaster who does not realize that.

1 Concealed itself also is not a defined game term (the game normally uses the term obscured, rather than concealed for vision). The only time it is used in the PHB besides the section on cover is when an illusion conceals the true nature of something. So its meaning is the common English meaning, which according to the dictionary means "kept secret; hidden"; but it really does not matter for your question if the curtain conceals its target or not -- what matters is if the concealment is by an obstacle or not. A wall of force or thick wall of crystal do not provide concealment, as they are not hiding their target - they are transparent and you can plainly see it.

I mean, when in doubt Fireball ;)

I mean, Fireball doesn't even work if the "curtain" is used instead as a "tent" or "blanket". https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93050/does-the-fireball-spell-ignore-total-cover . It's silly.

@nonymous Fireball is due to its special rules fir its area spreading round corners - you still cannot target a point behind s tent or curtain with it, but its area can reach there

According to the most upvoted answer, here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93050/does-the-fireball-spell-ignore-total-cover , 'If there are no corners this spell can successively travel around within it's effect radius to reach the target, then the target cannot be reached by the effect, and has total cover, causing it to ignore the effect entirely.' So, a blanket would do the trick for fireball. But, it would also, absurdly, shield a PC from an Archlich's Finger of Death.
