# Is this homebrew Chromatic Blade spell balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew-review

Honestly, this spell was my Eldritch Knight player's idea but I thought it interesting and am trying to work out the balance. It's sort of a hybrid of the *chromatic orb* and *green-flame blade* spells.

### Spell Concept

The idea is to imbue *chromatic orb*'s ability to pick the element, a powerful ability, into a melee attack with similar-ish splash damage. Something akin to the *dragon's breath* spell's short-range cone felt right.

### Current Draft

> #### *Chromatic Blade*
>
> *2nd-level evocation*
>
> **Casting Time:** 1 action
>   **Range:** 5 feet
>   **Components:** V, M (a weapon)
>   **Duration:** Instantaneous
>
> Your weapon gleams with incandescent light. You choose acid, cold, fire, lightning, poison, or thunder for the type of glow you create. As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack's normal effects, and elemental energy of that type bursts forth from your weapon in a 5-foot cone directed at the point of attack. Creatures within the cone's area of effect take 2d6 damage of the chosen elemental type.
>
> ***At Higher Levels.*** When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher, the damage increases by 1d6 for each slot level above 2nd.

#### Wording clarifications for reading purposes

- *"Incandescent"* tends to mean "glows from being heated" (like an
  incandescent light bulb). The nearest alternative I could think of
  was radiant, and while I think that's a better fit semantically, that
  is already its own damage type (and intentionally not one of the
  options here to keep in line with *chromatic orb*). I could just say
  "chromatic light", but chromatic is just the light spectrum already
  so that's lame/nonsense.
- *"directed at the point of attack*" is a little awkward, but the intent
  is "from you in the direction of the attack". Unsure on the best wording
  there to represent this.
- *"Cone of 5-ft. radius"*: The intent of the spell is to represent an
  area like so:

  ```
   | | |X|
   |O|X|X|
   | | |X|
  ```

  With the O being the caster, and the Xs being the targets. So the
  cone would include the hit target of the melee attack (like
  *green-flame blade*) and proceed to jump to the 3 adjacent/back tiles
  (back, diagonal up, diagonal down). If there's a better way to word
  that part in general, I'd be open to it.

#### Balance considerations

My thinking was that being able to pick your element is a powerful feature of *chromatic orb*, and giving it an AOE effect both warranted it dealing less direct damage than the nearest equivalents (1 casting of *chromatic orb* and 1 spray of *dragon's breath*). Math comparisons of similar abilities/attacks/spells:

- *chromatic orb*: 1st-level spell, does 3d8 of chosen type to a
  single target based on spell attack roll (averaging 13.5 on a hit)
- *dragon's breath*: 2nd-level spell, does 3d6 per breath (average 10.5
  per target) but with a save so at least some guaranteed damage
  (average 5.25 on a save per target) and across a 15-foot cone (bigger
  area than proposed)
- dragonborn breath weapon: once per short rest and character-specific
  (like from a red dragonborn), does 2d6 of your draconic ancestry's
  elemental type (average 7 per target) with an associated save for
  half damage (average 3.5 per target) for a 5-foot cone (same area)
- *scorching ray*: 2nd-level spell, 3 individual ranged attack rolls
  for 2d6 fire damage per hit (average 7 per hit)
- *green-flame blade*: cantrip, melee hit + fire damage on additional
  creature within 5 feet based on your spell modifier (1-5 realistically)

All of the above scale to include an extra damage die per level, or in the case of green flame blade, being a cantrip, at select player levels.

#### Alternatives/options speculated

- Could perhaps use a save for the elemental damage, Dex or Con
  respective to the element chosen like normal)

  - Pro(s): fits closer to the *dragon's breath* spell's damage per
    target (also 2nd level)
  - Con(s): spell already requires a struck melee attack before it does
    anything and that then means its a roll per target, which I know
    lots of spells do but just adds to the complexity of the mechanics
- Could make it just a single additional target within 5ft of the melee
  attack target.

  - Pro(s): Would make it fit a little closer to Green Flame Blade's effect
  - Con(s): then the damage at face value seems a little underwhelming
    being 2d6 per target (though in its current form of not needing
    a secondary save for each target in the cone, it's potentially up to
    melee weapon + 8d6 damage in total, compared to 6d6 for all 3 rays
    hitting for *scorching ray*, and you get to pick the damage type for
    this, though a more realistic situation of melee target + 1 extra
    is melee + 4d8 chosen damage)
- Could increase/decrease the damage dealt or increase the range if the
  damage seems right but maybe not enough AOE (more similarly scoped to
  *dragon's breath* spell, also 2nd-level)

  Overall, is this homebrew *chromatic blade* spell balanced? How could it be improved?

Comment: I don't think this is an answer since it's not addressing balance, but the cone depicted in your diagram is a 10-foot cone. See the definition of ["cone"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Cone) under "Areas of Effect" in the Spellcasting chapter of the PHB/basic rules.

Comment: @V2Blast Technically the depicted cone isn't any standard cone, as it is 10ft long and 15 ft. wide wereas the standard ones use the same measure on both.

Comment: @Someone_Evil: Good point.

Comment: Check out various words with the -escent suffix to see which fits your effect. Luminescent? Phosphorescent? https://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-escent-suffix/

Comment: @V2Blast I'm a little unsure how representative the given examples are for RAW intentions here, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46492/how-do-i-map-a-15-cone-to-a-1-grid, but the 2nd image has the 1 tile into 3 tiles from "centered horizontal aim" type scope depicted. Would a more Raw version be more like 123 tiles affected then? Or, other depictions given in the link above, using the point of origin being a corner of a given tile (though to me that feels awkward personally).

Comment: @redrascal you will struggle to find a raw reference for a 10ft come as it is non standard. I would just list it at 10ft and play it the way you want. If someone else uses your spell in a different game they can interpret it for themselves. 15ft would be more raw and in line with things like burning hands and dragons breathe but would also affect the power of the spell.

Comment: @linksassin a tangentially related question of "why pick burning hands over dragons breath?" Best I can tell they're both L2, both 3d6, both a save, both wizard/sorcerer available. One's evocation, fire, instantaneous. One's transmutation, one of several, continuous so can be used repeatedly. Dragon's breath seems objectively better with the main drawback for my Eldritch Knight player being that Transmutation means he can't pick up the latter. I guess also can't stack dragon's breath + other conc is the other downside.

Comment: @Redrascal *Burnings Hands* is a 1st level spell. It doesn't require concentration and also has a benefit in the action economy. Dragon's breathe needs to be set up as a bonus action, then an action used to activate it.

Comment: @linksassin you are correct. Apparently I can't read and thought Burning hands was first level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## This is a great start

I always love when player's have a idea for a unique ability they want for their character so even if this was slightly over-powered I would consider allowing it. Overall it looks pretty good and I think you've done a good job and thinking through the balance of the spell overall. I'll just highlight a few things that I noticed from reading it.

#### "Incandescent light" is ambiguous

While I thematically understand what you were going for. Emitting light is a mechanical term in D&D and "incandescent" isn't one of the types. It would be better to simply stick with "dim light" or "bright light" and specify a distance. Or if you don't intend for it to emit light, consider rewording or removing this entirely.

#### The area of effect is wrong

A 5 foot cone would only hit the first target. I think the correct area for the effect you want is a 10 foot cone originating from you and directed toward the target of the attack.

#### Damage is underwhelming

For a second level spell the damage isn't that spectacular. Of the spell you compare it too, *Scorching Ray* has significantly more range and *Dragon's breathe* has up to 10 activation per casting. I think you could consider increasing this, consider spells such as *Burnings Hands* and *Ice Knife* in your comparison.

#### No save for additional targets

Basically this is a AoE spell that only requires an attack roll against the closest enemy in the range. If used cleverly you could attack a low AC target and have a high AC target as one of the additional targets which would then take automatic damage. Instead I would consider something like the Ice Knife mechanic where the additional effect is trigger hit or miss but allows a saving throw for half damage.

#### Missing the attack roll is a big cost

Currently there is a huge opportunity cost to cast this spell. Assuming the fighter is at least level 5 they are giving up their extra attack and a second level spell slot for the chance to do some extra damage. If they miss the attack roll it is all wasted.

I would suggest either activating the effect hit or miss as mentioned above or looking at the Paladin's smite spells that activation on the next melee hit instead of as part of the action to cast it.

#### Conclusion

I like the spell overall, I think its a good start. And while I think it could be improved I don't think it is so unbalanced that I would ban it at my table. If you do make changes remember that each of the comments I made were to that issue in isolation. Some of the issues are related so if you modify one consider how it effects the others.

Good luck and remember to wait at least 3 days before posted an new iteration to give time for multiple answer to come in.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Not intending to shed light, was just a thematic "glow" to indicate the element. Maybe just brandishing the weapon in some way or leave it out entirely like you said and leave it up to interpretation. Thanks for correction on 10ft. I like the "always exude the element with a save" rather than relying on hit. Bumping damage to 3d6 is probably warranted and if increased range to 15-ft then it's basically melee burning hands. I guess my main concern with giving it too much damage was the ability to change the element. Wasn't sure how much weight to give that.

Comment: @redrascal You can get an idea of how much weight to give by comparing chromatic orb (L1 3d8) to spells like guiding bolt (L1 4d6+advantage), ray of sickness (L1 2d8+poisoned) and acid arrow (L2 4d4+2d4). Basically it seems like not much imo. Chromatic orb is a pretty decent damage spell even ignoring the option to control the type. Therefore compare your spell to things like burning hands and ice knife and give a similar level of damage at the same level.

Comment: The other option to fix the "opportunity cost" could be to make it like a smite spell - you cast the spell as a bonus action, hold concentration, and then apply the effect on the first hit. If you do that, the damage / level comparison should look to the smite spells, and then scale down a little since those aren't AoE spells.

Comment: @linksassin the burning hands and ice knife comparison are very apt. Bumping the damage to 3d6 makes it a "melee choose your element" burning hands with a slightly shorter range (even at suggested but intended 10-ft cone rather than given 5-ft)

Comment: @codeMonkey Making it a concentration spell with a "unleash held damage on hit" isn't a bad idea. Would leave it as potential to lose it through concentration checks (though if you're the presumed fighter you're probably pretty good at those) but safer on not being a single die roll to hit/miss. I think if I was going to go that route though it being an AOE doesn't make as much sense. I believe all of the smite spells/abilities are single target? Could leave it single and bump up the damage or leave it lower as AOE.

Comment: @Redrascal If you're going to emulate a smite, then deciding which smite you want and at which level to start will guide you in your damage output. Figuring out the rider equivalent is the harder bit.

Comment: @Redrascal - exactly. The con check adds some risk, but the on-hit release makes it much more reliable compared to straight hit-or-miss. Could add a saving throw for half damage. For the AoE damage - I like the idea of an AoE smite. That doesn't exist, but feels flavorful and interesting. I would just dial down the damage some. Maybe drop one die from the equivalent level smite.

Comment: @codeMonkey spell smites seem to be bonus action, concentration, on your next hit do "more damage" with some secondary effect to a single target. Also don't believe there's an AOE smite. If we went down this path I guess the question would become "is losing the secondary effect equivalent to giving it AOE and/or allowing choice of element". One or the other I could see, both probably needs the damage mitigated some.

Comment: @NautArch smite comparisons: searing and wrathful are 1d6 damage L1, thunderous is 2d6 L1, branding is 2d6 L2, blinding 3d8 l3. All single target with varying effects (loosely tied to level cast) with fire, psychic, thunder or radiant damage respectively (mostly better options other than searing). Allowing a save on the AOE aspect mitigates the damage some but  I'm unsure if that's enough to compensate 2d6 damage (matching L2 branding smite). Could maybe argue concentration compensates for picking element as well but I'd argue that's probably better for the presumed caster, an Eldritch Knight.

Comment: @Redrascal Concentration remains for the smite spells, too, so that's a wash.

Comment: @linksassin about ready to make an updated version of this based on asking my player their preference and the feedback given so far. If I think it's different enough is it worth making it a new question and linking back to this for context? Or make an Edit with the new/updated version first but collapsing (is that a thing? or similar?) the old version to make it clear that that's "old."

Comment: @Redrascal You might like to read [how to write a good homebrew review question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/48759). Also our policy to [wait 72 hours between versions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9151/48759). I think based on how you wrote this question and your point that it is different and it is close enough to 72 hours that you can go ahead and post it as a separate question and link to this one for context.

Comment: @linksassin I've made a new post with the updated spell https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168806/is-this-homebrew-chromatic-smite-spell-balanced and am interested in your thoughts. I will admit up front that my 3d8 damage was from accidentally comparing against L3 Blinding Smite instead of L2 Branding Smite. I would drop it to 2d8, perhaps even 2d6 to match Branding Smite, depending on the input I get for comparing the secondary effects of the smites to the ability to choose your element and minor splash bonus.

Comment: @Redrascal I saw question, but haven't had time to review it yet. I'm impressed with the amount of effort and thought you put into it between revisions, well done.

Answer (score 2):

## Needs some work, but interesting concept

The spells that seem similar to me to balance against are the Smite spells (with effects on hit) and *elemental weapon.*

The problem is that you are kind of combining both of these, and I think the spell level is too low because of it.

The 2nd level smite spell is *branding smite* which starts 2d6 damage and then has a continuing rider removing a condition (invisibility) as the concentration effect.

*Elemental Weapon* is a third level concentration spell that turns a nonmagical weapon into a +1 weapon and adds another 1d4 damage of the elemental damage type you choose.

My reasoning for including *elemental weapon* is the inclusion of elemental damage. For monsters that the character knows are vulnerable or resistant to damage they are already dealing, this is a big deal. That freedom of choosing damage type is not something to be ignored.

Your spell seems to merge the two by adding 2d6 damage of your type choice and then instead of a condition rider, it turns into an area effect.

The latter aspect of that is a big deal - especially for melee weapon casters that may not have a lot of area effect options. It's situational, but 2nd level feels a bit low and I think this is more of a 3rd level spell to put it with *elemental weapon*. It deals more damage, but only one attack, so I think that's the balance there.

Comment: I'm not sure *elemental weapon* is a fair comparison. That has a duration of 1 hour and applies on every hit. This is a single melee attack with an additional aoe effect. I agree with your point on smite but personally find this underpowered for second level rather than over powered.

Comment: Not sure Elemental Weapon is a fair comparison as it can last a full hour with concentration. That's a lot of swings. This is a single attack, so more like smite to that effect. I do agree making it an AOE is potentially a powerful option for an otherwise limited melee character though, at least in it's current iteration, the opportunity cost is rather high for it (presumably used by a melee fighter in the first place which is giving up two attacks to cast the spell and can still miss).

Comment: @linksassin I added some more support on why *elemental weapon* needs to be considered. You can disagree, but that's why you've got your different answer :)

Comment: @Redrascal I added more detail to why it's important to consider *elemental weapon*. Freedom of choice of damage types is a big nice to have.

Comment: That's alright. Agree to disagree, I do see your point and why you included it but I think you are still understating the difference in duration and therefore potential damage. Also consider that with repeat attacks elemental weapon is likely going to work at some point while this spell as written is hit or miss. I wouldn't like to spend a 3rd level slot on something with moderate damage that might not even work. Particularly as a half caster and this is intend for an eldritch knight.

Comment: @linksassin And they can also lose concentration and drop the spell during all of this. As well as the fact that if they're casting this spell, there's a good chance they already have a magic weapon and can't actually use it.

Comment: @NautArch definitely agree that being able to choose the damage type is powerful. It's the main reason I leant on keeping the damage low. That and it getting spread to more targets potentially than green flame blade. This iteration is intended as a 2nd level spell though, and best comparisons I could make means this might be just slightly underwhelming. The "AOE"ness of this is of a lesser concern as well since it's a short range cone. If it was more like melee strike+ thunderwave it would be a bigger problem as that has a larger affected space (though also more damage as a 1st level spell).

Comment: @Redrascal I'm actually a bit unclear as to what the goal of this spell is. Is it to work like Chromatic Orb and be single target elemental damage? Or is it supposed to add damage AND hurt more creatures? The fact that this situational opportunity to affect multiple targets is why I'm suggesting high er level.

Comment: @NautArch it was described to me by the player as "an upcast green flame blade". Taking that literally would be increase of damage on the melee target (assuming the "scaled" portion means cast at higher levels) and some bonus on an adjacent target. I've personally conflated it to be more a cone as those were easier comparisons to other spells of similar levels and damage. So, to answer your question, the intention is to give a melee strike an aoe hit while being able to pick your element (again, agree that AOE + pick element are strong abilities, hence the balancing issue).

Comment: @Redrascal Green-flame only attacks one more target - this *could* do more. And the secondary damage is automatic (not based on save, so that's a consideration) and a static value at the lower levels.

Comment: @NautArch I've made a new post with the updated spell https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168806/is-this-homebrew-chromatic-smite-spell-balanced and am interested in your thoughts. I will admit up front that my 3d8 damage was from accidentally comparing against L3 Blinding Smite instead of L2 Branding Smite. I would drop it to 2d8, perhaps even 2d6 to match Branding Smite, depending on the input I get for comparing the secondary effects of the smites to the ability to choose your element and minor splash bonus.

Answer (score 1):

### Unavoidable damage is problematic

Running through similar options that come to mind, in rough order of avoidability:

- **Cloud of Daggers** (2nd level, 4d4 magical slashing AOE, **no** counter-play)
- **Heat Metal** (2nd level, 2d8 fire, **Don't wear armor** as counter-play)
- **Magic Missile** (1st level, 3d4+3 force, **Shield** as counter-play)
- **HP-limited** (e.g. Sleep, Power Word Kill, **Don't be weak** as counter-play)
- **Walls** (e.g. Fire, Prismatic, **Don't walk into them** as counter-play)
- **AOE blasts** (Usually save-for-half, **Evasion** as counter-play)
- **Reactive** (e.g. Armor of Agathys, **Stop hitting me** as counter-play)
- **On-hit effects** (e.g. Hunter's mark, requires hit, **Don't get hit** as counter-play)

As you can see the only thing even close to your blade is *Cloud of Daggers*, which is a bit of a funky spell already, and deals magical slashing damage.  Being able to choose an arbitrary element (nothing I know of is immune to all of the above, even Slaadi are acid, cold, fire, lightning, and thunder) means you can deal guaranteed damage (albeit small amounts of it) by tossing an unconscious rat into the air in front of you, which seems bad.

Unfortunately...

### Rolling for AOE on-hit effects is also problematic

Worst case it is only 3-4 rolls, but it still is also unprecedented and slows down combat for an extra 7 average damage.

### Best bet - leave it as-is and reserve the right to change if abused

I think it is a neat effect and idea, and it's your game!